# How do you bypass error message The changes you requested to the table were not successful

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am building a barcode entry form in Microsoft Access. As part of this form, it inserts the current date/time into a field in the Table, along with the barcode value. In my table, date/time is indexed (no duplicates). My problem is if the same barcode value is scanned multiple times within 1 second (i.e. same time), then I get the "The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship." error popup.

Because this form will be used for mass barcode entry by multiple barcode scanners, I need it to never pop up with an error message. If it encounters one of these errors, I basically want it to ignore it because if there is a duplicate value then obviously it was just a double scan or something. I basically want to suppress all errors, or at least this particular error.

I have thought about assigning a random number of seconds to the date/time, and that may work however I think it could still happen just less often.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Where is your code that inserts/edits the barcode number?
have you tried to set a where condition like (where barcode not already exists?)

Comment: There is no code specifically that inserts the barcode number. It is entered into the barcode number field on a form while in the data-entry mode. Adding a like condition sounds like a good idea, but where specifically or how should I incorporate that?

Comment: I have not idea what your system is :) but you can either unbound and use sql execution or you can use form_before insertevent/before update event to check the barcode